# Loading data into DIV in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I tried jQuery get function and coded the below. What is wrong with my below code? Its not working.

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#Layer1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:1;
}
-->
</style>
<div id="Layer1"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.get('http://google.com/', null, function(data)
    {$('#Layer1').append(data);
}, 'html');
</script>
```

Comment: If you are really using `google.com` then its a cross domain request, which should not work.

Comment: I tried even ` jQuery.get('test.html', null, function(data)` but no use :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get data from [a different origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which isn't allowed for security reasons.

Comment: I tried even ` jQuery.get('test.html', null, function(data)` but no use :(

Comment: If you want to get data from a different origin the only option is JSONP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: try $.get('test.html', function(data)...); no null as second paramter